# Multimeter fails to measure forward voltage

Tags: led, voltage-measurement

I have a MS8233D Multimeter and wanted to measure the forward voltage of some LEDs.

I connected the leads directly to the LED and used the Diode Testing Mode.

However the multimeter just displays Ol and the LED does not light up.

I was also unable to measure continuity with this multimeter. No beeping sounds.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcWQnS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

As an alternative I used this circuit and measured the voltage by touching the anode and cathode of the LED. Using the V DC setting.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f94pWE.png)</sup>

The lowest readings I got were around 1.9 V for my green and yellow LEDs. 2.9 V for the white ones.

The manual states 1.48 V open circuit voltage.

Does this mean the multimeter does not supply enough voltage to effectly power the LEDs and thus cannot read the forward voltage? Is my technique of measuring even correct?

Comment: *The manual states 1.48 V open circuit voltage.* That relates to the **diode test** function of the DMM. When using this you **must not** use your circuit with the 9V battery and the resistor. With the circuit the DMM would then see more than 1.48 V and display OI which is what you get.

Comment: When using the circuit with the 9V battery you **MUST** set the meter to the DC Voltage range !!!! Not the diode test. *Is my technique of measuring even correct?* Nope, it is not. Use the DC Voltage range with the 9V battery and the resistor and then it will be correct.

Comment: I edited the question. I used the diode test function and connected the DMM directly to the LED. The circuit with the 9V battery was my other try at figuring out the forward voltage. I then used the voltage range setting.

Comment: Your method looks fine, there are some DMM's that don't have enough compliance to measure LED's.

Comment: Thank you all! That's what I figured and now I have confirmation. I take it that's the same reason why continuity with LEDs does not work.